# Keeping Shaders in Memory

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, shaders, memory-management

Is it possible to make Blender keep shaders in memory instead of reloading them each time I switch back to lookdev or render view?

I am losing a lot of time switching between the views simply because the shaders have to load...it can take up to 3 or 4 minutes. I work as much in the basic viewport as possible for speed, but I do need to switch to check textures, lights and things. Unless it is only a short time, Blender has to reload all the shaders again.

There MUST be a way to get Blender to hold the shaders in memory so it is possible to quickly switch between manipulating things in the viewport and checking the effect in shaded view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered an answer to this:

Preferences/System/Memory & Limits/Texture Time Out

I had this set as default to 120 (seconds I am presuming). It is possible to set it to 0 so that they are kept in memory.

What would be nice is if it were possible to load or unload textures manually. Often, we are working on lighting and textures for a while and then sometimes modelling and animation.

Comment: Thanks for that - I didn't know to do that.