# “Preload” Textures

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

is there an option to ‘preload’ images and textures?
Because everytime i want to enter renderview (cycles with OptiX) it takes a lot of time to get all the images together.
Or is there any other option to decrease my rendertime in renderview?

Thanks!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190317/keeping-shaders-in-memory